# Visual Studio OWIN Self-hosted App deployment

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, signalr, owin

I've got an OWIN Self-Hosted SignalR app. I'm looking for a way to automatically deploy it to a different server (one is local, one is in Azure cloud) from Visual Studio. I'm not using IIS, I want to run it either as a normal app or as a Windows service.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to consider using [**TopShelf**](https://topshelf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html)

and here is the [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Topshelf/)

All you need is to build and deploy the bin folder then just run one command

Comment: Is there any way to automate the process of uploading and reinstalling the service on my remote server?

Comment: Yes sure. But it's up to the way that you automate your work. For us, we're using VSTS and we just run topshelf command to uninstall the service then copy the new bin folder and run install command again